# Where is the missing key?

Tags: c#

I have a decimal number list like that :

```
0.01
0.03
0.10
0.18
0.24
0.28
0.30
0.31
0.33
0.55
2.34
3.37
9.19
9.22
10.28
```

I would like to group this numbers like that:
if the difference between first and second number is 0.02; this should be in same key in KeyValuePair list..

I have a method like below :

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, float>> NumberingAngles(List<float> angleList)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, float>> numberedList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, float>>();
    numberedList.Clear();
#region BETA ACILARI TIPLENDIR
    float sonDeger = 0f;
    int z = 0;
    float ilkDeger = 0f;
    int mB = 2;
    float difference = 0f;
    float tipFarki = 0f;
    foreach (float item in angleList)
    {

        difference = Convert.ToSingle((item - sonDeger).ToString("0.00"));

        if (difference > 0.02f)
        {
            numberedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, float>(mB, item));
            sonDeger = item;
            mB++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (z == 0)
            {
                ilkDeger = item;
                z++;
            }
            tipFarki = item - ilkDeger;
            if (tipFarki > 0.02f)
            {
                numberedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, float>((mB - 1), item));
                sonDeger = item;
                mB++;
                ilkDeger = 0f;
                z = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                numberedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, float>((mB - 1), item));
                sonDeger = item;
            }
        }             
    }
#endregion
    return numberedList;
}
```

The problem is : When I get the results in a KeyValuePair List, some keys are missing like number 7.. It jumps 6 to 8 as you see below. How can I solve this issue.. Maybe this can be very easy to solve fore someones..

The results are like below..

```
1 0.01
1 0.03
2 0.10
3 0.18
4 0.24
5 0.28
5 0.30
6 0.31
6 0.33
8 0.55
9 2.34
10 3.37
11 9.19
12 9.22
13 10.28
```

Comment: what is it for? Convert.ToSingle((item - sonDeger).ToString("0.00"))

Comment: where is 7 in the input list?

Comment: @MariusBancila, I think, 7 is a key. and the input list contains values

Comment: You are defining the first elements (int) in your KeyValuePair from "mB - 1", where mb is not the current counter, but a variable which in some iterations is modified but in some others is not. You should put a counter being modified every time (together with sonDeger = item; written just once, not inside each condition).

Comment: I recommend you to move operations like sonDeger = item; to outer loop. In this case you reduce the probability of mistake.

Comment: And you certanly have to rewrite the code. because it's unreadable and ununderstandable. And it does a lot of excess work.

Comment: Yes. input lists contains values.

Comment: What happens if you have the numbers `0.01`, `0.03` and `0.05`? The first and second going to slot one. The second and the third should also go into the same slot, but that is not slot one, cause the difference between the first and third values are too big.

Comment: if the difference between 0.05 and 0.01, it should be in slot two. For example : `Slot One :0.01 0.03,  Slot two: 0.05 0.06`. That is the difference between the numbers of two slots should be smaller than 0.02.

Comment: Sorry, That is the difference between the numbers of two slots should be bigger than 0.02. –

Comment: So this means the first number that leads to a slot creation defines the lower bound of the slot and the upper bound automatically gets (lower bound + 0.02)?

Comment: Yes, that is true Oliver. As you can see in the results above.. 0.28 and 0.30 in slot 5. 0.31 and 0.33 in slot 6. As you can see 0.30 and 0.31 not in same slot because of the lower bound of slot 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply rewrote this thing and made a little refactoring. Here is what comes out:

A slot class that holds all elements belonging to some specific range of values:

```
public class Slot
{
    private double _LowerBound;
    private double _UpperBound;
    private List<double> _Values;

    public Slot(double lowerBound, double upperBound)
    {
        if (upperBound < lowerBound)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The upper bound must be greater or equal the lower bound.");

        _LowerBound = lowerBound;
        _UpperBound = upperBound;

        _Values = new List<double>();
        _Values.Add(lowerBound);
        Values = _Values.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<double> Values { get; private set; }

    public void Add(double value)
    {
        if (!IsResponsible(value))
        {
            var message = String.Format("The value {0} is not greater or equal {1} or less or equal {2}.", value, _LowerBound, _UpperBound);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message);
        }

        _Values.Add(value);
    }

    public bool IsResponsible(double value)
    {
        return value >= _LowerBound
               && value <= _UpperBound;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Range: {0} - {1}, Elements: {2}", _LowerBound, _UpperBound, _Values.Count);
    }
}
```

A SlotCollection class that is responsible to hold all defined ranges:

```
public class SlotCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, double>>
{
    private List<Slot> _Slots;
    private double _TolerancePerSlot;

    public SlotCollection(double tolerancePerSlot)
    {
        if(tolerancePerSlot < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("tolerancePerSlot must be greater or equal zero.", "tolerancePerSlot");

        _TolerancePerSlot = tolerancePerSlot;
        _Slots = new List<Slot>();
        Slots = new ReadOnlyCollection<Slot>(_Slots);
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Slot> Slots { get; private set; }

    public void Add(IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            Add(value);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, double>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _Slots.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<int, double>(i, _Slots[i].Values.First());
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private void Add(double value)
    {
        var matchingSlot = _Slots.FirstOrDefault(slot => slot.IsResponsible(value));

        if (matchingSlot == null)
        {
            matchingSlot = new Slot(value, value + _TolerancePerSlot);
            _Slots.Add(matchingSlot);
        }
        else
        {
            matchingSlot.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Some kind of sample inputs:

```
var inputs = new List<double>()
{
    0.01, 0.03, 0.10, 0.18,
    0.24, 0.28, 0.30, 0.31,
    0.33, 0.55, 2.34, 3.37,
    9.19, 9.22, 10.28
};
```

And some sample usage of the code above:

```
var slots = new SlotCollection(0.02);
slots.Add(inputs);

// Spit out the desired user output.
foreach (var kvp in slots)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine();

// Output a more in depth view of the data distribution.
foreach (var slot in slots.Slots)
{
    Console.WriteLine(slot);

    foreach (var value in slot.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I know this class design is still far from perfect, but it should give you a good starting point on how to solve this problem a little better.

Comment: Thank you very much Oliver, I'll try with your solution.. Thanks for your valuable effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in:

```
numberedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, float>(mB, item));
```

it should be:

```
numberedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, float>(mB - 1, item));
```

BTW, I have no clue what your are doing... You really need to learn to step through with the debugger when you produce such voodoocode.

Comment: When I do this, the results are : `1 0.01
1 0.03
1 0.10
2 0.18
3 0.24
4 0.28
5 0.30
6 0.31
7 0.33
8 0.55
9 2.34
10 3.37
11 9.19
12 9.22
13 10.28`

Comment: I do not see missing number, so your `problem` is fixed... I see double number, that is because you do not have a mb++ in your last else. Just guessinng what can be wrong...

Comment: Sorry, no not yet solved. It shouldn't be the number 0.10 in key "1". And 0.30 and 0.31 should be in key "6".

Comment: You are asking to solve a problem without giving the specs of your problem. Start over and tell what your code should do, instead of voodoo programming and hoping someone can randomly make the change that fixes your program.

Comment: Sorry for woodoo programming but I really need to solve this. I may send my input and output files and code text in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this maybe:

```
float[] values = 
        {
            0.01f,
            0.03f,
            0.10f,
            0.18f,
            0.24f,
            0.28f,
            0.30f,
            0.31f,
            0.33f,
            0.55f,
            2.34f,
            3.37f,
            9.19f,
            9.22f,
            10.28f
        };


        Dictionary<int, float[]> kvp = new Dictionary<int, float[]>();
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 <= values.Length - 1)
            {
                if (Math.Round(values[i + 1] - values[i], 2) == .02d)
                {
                    kvp.Add(j, new float[] { values[i], values[i + 1] });
                    i++;                       
                }
                else
                    kvp.Add(j, new float[] { values[i] });
            }
            else               
                kvp.Add(j, new float[] { values[i] });

                j++;
        }

        foreach (var item in kvp)
        {             
            foreach (var i in item.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + i);
            }             
        }
```

Output:

```
1 0.01
1 0.03
2 0.1
3 0.18
4 0.24
5 0.28
5 0.3
6 0.31
6 0.33
7 0.55
8 2.34
9 3.37
10 9.19
11 9.22
12 10.28
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is a small problem. When I add "0.02" between 0.01 and 0.03 , then key of value "0.03" being 2 like `1 0.01 
1 0.02
2 0.03
3 0.1` That's I would like to see all these " 0.01 , 0.02, 0.03 " in same key "1" because of the differences between 0.03 - 0.01 = 0.02 (our rule)